# Cannot get Tab color or bar below tab to change reactjs

Tags: reactjs

As the title says, I am having a little trouble with styling my tab on my tab bar. This below is my code. I am trying to change the `TabIndicatorProps` and `inkBarStyle` but it doesnt seem to be affected by my code even if the other properties work.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
 
  },
}));


export default function NavTabs() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          variant="fullWidth"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="nav tabs" 
          TabIndicatorProps={{style: {background:'red'}}}
          inkBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#e77600'}}
        >
```

I have also commented out `const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({` and that had no effect on the color of my tabs. I also don't have any css which would over ride my tabs yet this is not working.
Appreciate any assistance in  this matter.

Regards

Comment: Are you using a UI library? If not, what is the implementation of the Tabs component? There is no telling if those props are being handled correctly within the component itself.

Comment: @RileyPagett I'm using MaterialUI